# Access a fragment editView from same fragment recycler.viewholder onClick() method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is a Fragment having a **Layout consisting of EditView and RecyclerView.**

The Recycler ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener to catch a Recycler row clicks.

My question is how can I access the EditView object from within the defined ViewHolder.OnClick (View v)

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          editText.setText(R.string.any_txt);

        }
```

The point of error is inside the ViewHolder constructor.

```
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);  //editText is always NULL, inaccessible
        }
```

I understand the View v here is a wrong View to find my

```
R.id.editText
```

How can I solve it?

Below is the fragment layout to demonstrate Views.Here you can find the editView and a recyclerView (having the ViewHolder I am talking about)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/groupsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextGroups"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_add_group"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewGroups"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textTopGroups"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextGroups">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTopGroups"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The shortes possible question is how to set editView.text on recycler row click ?**

Would like to add Ive implemented both onClick and OnLongClick and both do work. The point is only how to cast the editView.text property.

Comment: can you set all code inside fragment java file and xml file

Comment: Its a lot of code. What can I say is its runnig properly. Its just a cast case for editView View. How to cast a View from other part of the same Layout. Will put xml t show it.

Comment: Usually you pass some kind of callback (a custom interface which can transmit the relevant data in some method `onItemClick(YourDataClass clickedItemData)` ) into the RecyclerView.Adapter. As soon as the Button in the RecyclerView item is clicked, the callback will be notified and so the Fragment which is hosting both theRecyclerView and the EditText can now take care of changing the EditText

Comment: Like standard Activity interface ?

Comment: Do you want to change the content of `editTextGroups`?

Comment: Yes I want to change the .text of editTextGroups on ViewHolder item click.

Comment: Have found a solution, it's not so elegant. Ive just pass the editText into the ViewAdapter constructor so it's accessible from adapter and viewholder. But I do not like the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through abstraction. Here is an example:

**Adapter**

```
public class FruitsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FruitsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    OnFruitClickListener listener;


    List<ModelFruits> fruits;
    Context context;

    public FruitsAdapter(List<ModelFruits> fruits, Context context) {
        this.fruits = fruits;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_fruits, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder,final int position) {

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(fruits.get(position).getImage())
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.name.setText(fruits.get(position).getName());


      //Here we pass our data to the onClick method of our inteface
       holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               listener.onClick(R.string.anytext);
           }
       });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fruits.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        CardView root;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_image);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            root = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root);

        }
    }

    // a method to intialize the interface
    public void fruitOnClick(OnFruitClickListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;

    }

    public interface OnFruitClickListener{
        void onClick(String text);
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
        RecylerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        TextView myTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        adapter = new FruitsAdapter(DataSource.fruits,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.fruitOnClick(new FruitsAdapter.OnFruitClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(String text) {
                myTextView.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems more complicated then just having a ViewHolder onClick(this) and modified ViewAdapter constructor like `public ViewAdapter(EditText editGroupText)`. Same idea like passing the `context` in your example.

Comment: Though, in this example i have passed context to adapter class, we shouldn't pass your activity context like this (i have edited one of my older projects to show you how this can be done). There will be always a risk of memory leak. It may seem complicated but when you get a hang of this, you will be benefited in the future.